# Why Hibernate is running Update instead of Delete

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i am trying to delete a row from my child entity . Loan is my parent class and  DVLoanParticipants   is child class.  My Loan Object is looking like this to run delete .

```
 Loans(loanId=196777, dvLoanParticipantsMap={})
```

My Expectation is to delete the row from DVLoanParticipants  , but hibernate trying to run an update statement and failing.

```
@Entity
public class Loans {
        
@Id
@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;
    
@OneToMany(targetEntity = DVLoanParticipants.class, cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true )
@JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID")
@MapKey(name = "dvLoanParticipantsId.dvpParticipantName")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Map<String, DVLoanParticipants> dvLoanParticipantsMap;
}

@Entity
public class DVLoanParticipants  implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private DVLoanParticipantsId dvLoanParticipantsId;
}


@Embeddable
public class DVLoanParticipantsId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@Column(name = "DVP_PARTICIPANT_NAME")
private String dvpParticipantName;

}
```

The Update Statement is trying to execute is

```
update DV_LOAN_PARTICIPANTS set  LOAN_ID=null  where LOAN_ID=?
```

But why its running Update statement ? what i can do to run the delete statement?

Comment: Share example of the code you use to delete `DVLoanParticipants`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CascadeType.ALL` (specifically `CascadeType.REMOVE` here) doesn't mean the children will be removed if removed from the collection. It means that every state transition of the parent is cascaded to his child. Children are only removed automatically when the parent is deleted.

So by deleting the `DVLoanParticipants` in the collection, you are not asking Hibernate to delete the entity. You are asking him to update the record to point to no `Loans`, which results in a SQL update with `NULL` in the foreign key.

You need to had `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)` for Hibernate to remove a child when he is separated from his parents (it must be detached from **all** parents for it to work).

Comment: I tried with that but no luck , still getting same issue . Still its running Update statement

Comment: @OneToMany(targetEntity = DVLoanParticipants.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true )
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID",updatable = false)

Comment: Modified the code as above and now its working

Comment: @VKP thank you very much, updatable = false resolved my issue